# Merging 2 jquery functions that update two seperate DIVs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onchange

I wish for a select dropdown box to run two functions simultaneously in order to update two seperate divs on the same page.

here are my functions;

```
function showFAQ(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("faqHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("faqHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
   var category = "<?php echo $category; ?>";
    var catid = "<?php echo $catid; ?>";
    var subcat = "<?php echo $subcat; ?>";
    var subcat2 = "<?php echo $subcat2; ?>";
    var subcatid= "<?php echo $subcatid; ?>";
    var fileclass= "<?php echo $fileclass; ?>";
  xmlhttp.open("GET","FaqCheck.php?q="+str+ '&catid=' + catid + '&category=' + category + '&subcat=' + subcat + '&subcat2=' + subcat2 + '&subcatid=' + subcatid + '&fileclass=' + fileclass,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function showClass(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
   var category = "<?php echo $category; ?>";
    var catid = "<?php echo $catid; ?>";
    var subcat = "<?php echo $subcat; ?>";
    var subcat2 = "<?php echo $subcat2; ?>";
    var subcatid= "<?php echo $subcatid; ?>";
    var fileclass= "<?php echo $fileclass; ?>";
  xmlhttp.open("GET","FileCheck.php?q="+str+ '&catid=' + catid + '&category=' + category + '&subcat=' + subcat + '&subcat2=' + subcat2 + '&subcatid=' + subcatid + '&fileclass=' + fileclass,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

at the moment I am forced to use two drop down boxes to achieve but I would like it to be neater. the select code is;
1.

```
<select name="fileclass" onchange="showClass(this.value)" required="">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="create">Create</option>
<option value="modify">Modify</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>
```

2.

```
<select name="faq_class" onchange="showFAQ(this.value)" required="">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="create">Create</option>
<option value="modify">Modify</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>
```

for information, faq_class and fileclass share the same value (always!)

Thank you for helping a newbie :)

Comment: I don't see your dropdown list in your code. However, you can simply run 2 separate asynchronous ajax requests to fetch the data you need from the server and update the 2 divs.

Comment: Aside from the problem, I highly recommend using `$.get()` since you're already using jQuery, it'll reduce the amount of code needed and makes it much more readable.

Comment: @Dola just added the selection boxes (yummy)

Comment: @Dola I did try onchange="javascript: showClass(this.value);showFAQ(this.value);" but it does not seem to update both DIVs just the 'faqHint' DIV

Comment: You should not type `javascript:` in your onchange event. Just call the javascript functions directly. 
`onchange="showClass(this.value);showFAQ(this.value);`

Also, does it work properly when you call showClass in the change event of a separate dropdown list?

Comment: @Dola, i ammended the onchange to reflect only 'showClass(this.value);showFAQ(this.value);' but sometimes one of the DIVs does not update. If I ammend the second select box 'faqHint' with 'showClass(this.value)' or 'showFAQ(this.value)' I can update 'faqHint' that select box no problem with updating.

Comment: for information, each select box, when calling their own function, works a treat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the following in both functions. I have added the keyword `var` when initializing xmlhttp variable

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This is to make the scope of the variable to be only its containing function. if you initialize the variable without the `var` keyword, the variable will be attached to `window` object and will be seen globally.

**Edit**: Edited the code to show the full code

```
function showFAQ(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("faqHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   //used the keyword var before initializing xmlhttp variable
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
   var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("faqHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
   var category = "<?php echo $category; ?>";
    var catid = "<?php echo $catid; ?>";
    var subcat = "<?php echo $subcat; ?>";
    var subcat2 = "<?php echo $subcat2; ?>";
    var subcatid= "<?php echo $subcatid; ?>";
    var fileclass= "<?php echo $fileclass; ?>";
  xmlhttp.open("GET","FaqCheck.php?q="+str+ '&catid=' + catid + '&category=' + category + '&subcat=' + subcat + '&subcat2=' + subcat2 + '&subcatid=' + subcatid + '&fileclass=' + fileclass,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function showClass(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    //used the keyword var before initializing xmlhttp variable
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
   var category = "<?php echo $category; ?>";
    var catid = "<?php echo $catid; ?>";
    var subcat = "<?php echo $subcat; ?>";
    var subcat2 = "<?php echo $subcat2; ?>";
    var subcatid= "<?php echo $subcatid; ?>";
    var fileclass= "<?php echo $fileclass; ?>";
  xmlhttp.open("GET","FileCheck.php?q="+str+ '&catid=' + catid + '&category=' + category + '&subcat=' + subcat + '&subcat2=' + subcat2 + '&subcatid=' + subcatid + '&fileclass=' + fileclass,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And now you can call both functions in the `onchange` event of just one dropdown list like this:

```
onchange="showClass(this.value); showFAQ(this.value);"
```

Comment: would it be possible to show me with my existing code integrated please, I am a bit lost

Comment: @JohnD I have added the full code. Please check it and let me know if it's still not working

Comment: Ace, works a treat. :D (I would gladly vote for you but I only have 8 rep) maybe a vote for this question if you thought it was good :) and a big thanks

Comment: Glad it works, just an advice, try to learn and use jQuery, it will save you a lot of time and effort and you won't have to worry about browser compatibility. it's quite easy to learn as well. Good luck :)

Comment: @Dola jQuery is becoming less and less of a necessity, but in this case sure jQuery makes ajax simpler. However, this was a scoping error that could have happened even when using jQuery.

Comment: @Michael, well, I am not sure why you say that jQuery is becoming lessand less of a necessity. jQuery really saves time and effort. And in this case,if he used jquery, he wouldn't even need to initialize xmlhttp object

Comment: Could this code also update a cookie called fileclass with the value of the fileclass variable?